# procontroll library not working on windows 7 , 64 bit

Tags: processing, processing.js

I cant seem to figure out what I might be doing wrong here.

I have added the procontroll library at the library folder in my processing workspace. And then I am simply trying to run the check devices code to see if it detects the standard input systems and BAM!! there is an error. It doesn't say what is the dependency that might be missing except just it might not work on a windows 64 bit..

Am I doing something wrong or missing something obvious here? Just wanted to make sure before I start hunting for a 32 bit machine

Here is the screen shot of the console

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to take a look at this discussion on the Processing forum: http://forum.processing.org/two/discussion/3567/joysticks-in-processing-procontroll-library-help

Which includes this quote by user quark:

> You can download the native libraries for Windows 64 bit
>   (jinput-dx8_64.dll) from
>   [here](http://www.fileswap.com/dl/Pvu1tbgc/jinput-dx8_64.dll.html).
>
> Put this with the other jinput files and rename it jinput-dx8.dll
>   (replacing the existing file for 32 bit Windows), I tried this in
>   Windows 7 (64 bit) with Processing 2.1.1 and it worked for me.

Comment: --I did find that solution yesterday. I actually hit the same post you pointed at. And here is the updated library. 

http://www.lagers.org.uk/procontrol/index.html